# Enable scroll on dojo dijit.form.Select

Tags: dojo

I have a dijit.form.Select with 31 options. The options goes up to the end-of-page. How can I enable scroll so that the drop down doesn't expand down but shows scroll button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a `dijit.form.Select` there's an attribute called `maxHeight` that controls the height of the dropdown.

visit [this](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/form/Select.html#setting-height) link